# How to produce the right output of the special character, & in json?

Tags: json, discord, youtube, character, ifttt

I'm using IFTTT to post a video from a YouTube channel to a Discord server but the character that is in the title of the video didn't come out as it is.
The character came out as `&amp;` instead of the character `&`.

Thanks for the help, I appreciate it so much.

This is how I write the body:

```
{"content":"*{{Title}}*\n \n{{Url}}"}
```

This is the output:

```
From Alcoholic &amp; Drug Addict to Following Jesus!
 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q4pGhhabBbM
```

I want it to come out as:

```
From Alcoholic & Drug Addict to Following Jesus!
 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q4pGhhabBbM
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using `\&amp;` and it should work.
Basically use `\` before each special character you want to use.

Comment: Thank you for the response, @Jakub. May I know how to write the body so I can let the IFTTT know that it should always produce the character as written in the YouTube video?

For example, how should I write it in this body?
```
{"content":"*{{Title}}*\n \n{{Url}}"}
```